# Django 1.4 Modifying Custom Account Model for Uniqueness of E-mail Addresses

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've already defined a custom user account that utilizes several built in's from the auth User model and, using the user link, links these with some additional fields that I needed to register a user on the database.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

relevant from my models.py

```
# additional model to incorporate our custom fields to the auth user model                                                                                   
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)      #link (pointer) to the users other information in User model                                                      
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank = True, ) # True makes this field optional                                                                            
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER_CHOICE, null = True, blank = True)                                                                                    

    def __unicode__(self):            # define a unicode for the user to access                                                                              
        return u'%s %s' % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)   # return first and last name in shell  


# custom form to gather information from the user for a new account                                                                                          
class UserRegistration(UserCreationForm):
#class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):                                                                                                                    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "username", "password1", "password2",)

    # ensures uniqueness of user email addresses when registering                                                                                         
    def clean_email(self):
        print "In custom creation"
        email = self.cleaned_data.get(email = 'email')
        username = self.cleaned_data.get(username = 'username')
        # checks if email address already exists                                                                                                          
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact = self.cleaned_data['email']):
            print "Email exists"
#           if email and User.objects.filter(email__iexact = email).exclude(username=username).exists():                                                     
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email Address is currently used by another user.')
        return email
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

relevant from views.py

```
def Main(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        latest_events = Event.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:10] # Returns latest 10 events                                                              
        my_events = Event.objects.filter(creator=request.user)[:10]   # Returns up to 10 events created by current User                                       
        my_calendars = Calendar.objects.filter(creator=request.user)  # Returns all calendars created by the user                                             
        authForm = None
        loginForm = None
        headerType = "header.html"
    else:
        latest_events = None
        my_events = None
        my_calendars = None
        headerType = "header_main.html"

        authForm = UserRegistration(request.POST or None)
        print "Creating account UserRegistration" # TESTING PRINT                                                                                             
        print "User email = %s " %(User._meta.get_field('email'))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if authForm.is_valid():
                newUser = authForm.save(commit=False)
                newUser.save()
                newUser = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                login(request, newUser)

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/signup/')
....
....
more code on success redirection
....
....
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(I hope I didn't post too much code, just wanted to be thorough)

As you can see there are a few commented out attempts I've made recently.  I tried using thee built in RegistrationFormUniqueForm() by downloading 'registration' but I don't actually want to make a new registration form since I already have a working one.

I moved on to trying another suggestion, the code under the comment

```
# custom form to display additional sign up information
```

When I tried registering a new user with an already registered email it did not throw any error and allowed the registration.  I also tried changing the users email and it allowed the change to an already taken email with no objection.

Can anyone suggest a method for making user registration maintain a unique lock on each individual attempting to register with an email address that may already be taken? As well as preventing them from changing their email to one that is taken by a current user?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I made changes to the Models registration form def clean_email()   and the def in views to reflect what I currently have that still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indentation of your `clean_email` methods is wrong for both forms. At the moment, they are methods of the `Meta` class, so will never be called. For example, the registration form should be:

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
#class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):                                                                                                                    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "username", "password1", "password2",)

    def clean_email(self):
        """ensures uniqueness of user email addresses when registering"""
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
```

This might not be the real problem -- it's easy to get the indentation wrong when pasting code into stack overflow. If that's the case, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: No, that's actually how it is.  I was wondering about that but from the example I read that was how they posted it so I figured they knew something that maybe I didn't.  I will try that and let you know.  Thanks

Comment: I made changes to the code indentation and it still doesn't raise an error for entering an already in use email address.  Can anyone offer any ideas on a way to go about solving this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've changed your code, please update your question so that it's exactly the same. Then try adding some print statements or logging to try and work out what is going on. Is the clean method called when you think it should be? Does the queryset contain the items it should. Hopefully you'll be able to spot the problem.